# Selecting count of values in multiple columns using two tables

Tags: t-sql

I'm still new to tsql and trying to figure out how to build this query.

I have two tables. One called mirror which has an official list of all campuses and is used to populate a drop down list of campuses for users on a webform. They then have 5 choices they can select, which then populates another table with their request when they submit the form(Request). ie. CampusChoice1, CampusChoice2..etc.

I am trying to build a page to display the end results of all the collected data. After some reading I'm thinking I might need to use PIVOT to make this happen but I can't get my head to see the query.

I can make a rudimentary query for each choice1-5, but I kind of wanted them all together will nulls or zeros where some campuses were not chosen. 
Something like

--Simple count on single col
SELECT CampusChoice1, COUNT(*) as '#'
FROM Request
Group By CampusChoice1

Or 
--But this doesn't give the results I want, since it does not account for all the POSSIBLE choices.
SELECT CampusChoice1, COUNT(*) as '#',
              CampusChoice2, COUNT(*) as '#',
              CampusChoice3, COUNT(*) as '#',
              CampusChoice4, COUNT(*) as '#',
              CampusChoice5, COUNT(*) as '#'
FROM Operations.dbo.TransferRequest
Group By CampusChoice1, CampusChoice2, CampusChoice3, CampusChoice4, CampusChoice5

Any ideas how I could show this? Am I on the right track at least with the PIVOT table?

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with c#?

Comment: sorry..i am ultimately using this query to build a chart or maybe just a gridview in c#. Trying to nail down the query first. I removed the tag.

Comment: Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but assuming that you have this:

```
CampusChoice  | Other data ...
------------------------------
CampusChoice1 | ...
CampusChoice2 | ...
CampusChoice1 | ...
```

Then for the example above with only 3 rows you want this end result:

```
CampusChoice1 | 2 | CampusChoice2 | 1 | CampusChoice3 | 0 | ...
```

The T-SQL to achieve this is:

```
select
    'CampusChoice1',
    sum( case when CampusChoice = 'CampusChoice1' then 1 else 0 end ) '#',
    'CampusChoice2',
    sum( case when CampusChoice = 'CampusChoice2' then 1 else 0 end ) '#',
    'CampusChoice3',
    sum( case when CampusChoice = 'CampusChoice3' then 1 else 0 end ) '#',
    ...
from
    ...
```

Use the sum combined with the case to sum 1's for each row for CampusChoice1 and 0's for each row not CampusChoice1, repeating this for each CampusChoiceN.

Comment: Sorry. wish i could include an img but I'm too new.
The Requests table is mult cols like ID, TimeStamp, UserID, then CampusChoice1, CampusChoice2, CampusChoice3...etc. Each is a varchar with the name of the campus the user selected from a dropDownList on a form.

Comment: Don't worry, just tell me if I understood the question correctly or not. If not, what I misunderstood?

Comment: Its actually like this (there are 5 cols in the Request Table & 113 campuses)
id |... CampusChoice 1 | CampusChoice2  | CampusChoice3  | etc ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |... AAA Elem            | DDD Elem            | XXX MS
2  |... BBB Elem            | AAA Elem             | ZZZ HS
3  |... CCC Elem           | XXX MS                | TTT Elem